# NodeJS throughs error when serving a server on a VPS

Tags: node.js, linux, server, ip

I am trying to setup a node server on my VPS. When I run a simple http server script

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello, World!\n');
});

const ipAddress = 'my_public_ip'; // Replace with your VPS IP address
const port = 80;

server.listen(port, ipAddress, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${ipAddress}:${port}/`);
});
```

I get following error:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available my_public_ip:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1710:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1775:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1924:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1754:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: -99,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: 'my_public_ip',
  port: 80
}
```

I have allowed port 80 in ufw and node, npm, build-essential are installed. Can anyone help in resolving this?
This thing works fine on localhost in my VPS as it should but, as soon as I change the hostname to my public IP address, it gives the above error.

Comment: @Philippe I have tried many other ports as well. It is not working with any port.

Comment: Change `ipAddress` to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: this solved the problem @Philippe. Thanks a lot. Could you explain what happened here?